# How do I find the sum of the series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{7}40 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = \frac{635}{8}$$

The image of the orginial eqn is on the link above and so is the answer, but I need help in how to solve it.
when I did solve it I got $$\displaystyle 5(\frac{127}{8})$$

What did I do wrong? when solving:
$$r=1/2$$
$$Ag=40$$
$$n=7$$
So I plugged in everything into the formula:
$$\begin{align}
\sum &=Ag \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\\
&= 40 \frac{1-(1/2)^7}{1-1/2}\\
&=40\frac{1-1/128}{2/2-1/2}\\
&=49\frac{128/128-1/128}{1/2}\\
&=40\frac{127/128}{1/2}\\
&=40\frac{127}{128}\cdot\frac21\\
&=40\frac{127}{64}\cdot 1\\
&=5\frac{127}8\end{align}$$

Comment: I've edited your post into Latex, in future pls format equations properly and don't just link them. Also, what did you try? We can't figure out what you did wrong if you don't know what you did. This is a simple geometric series.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit what I have done and how I got my answer.

Comment: here I'll show you guys right now

Comment: Certainly the numerator must be divisible by $5$.

Comment: I'm so sorry with all the mess ups, sorry :(

Comment: What do you think $5\cdot 127$ is?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews 625..yeh..yeh i knw..im very stupid-thank you so much!! :) I very much appreciate your guys assistance! Thank YOU!!!

Comment: Well, $635$, actually. :)

Comment: YEP---wow...lol..I feel really stupid-please dont rub it in :( :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked specifically about your mistake. The glaring error is that $\displaystyle \frac{128}{2} = 64$, not $16$ (in the cancellation step).

But this may have been a typo, because your final answer is actually correct. $\displaystyle 5(\frac{127}{8}) = \frac{635}{8}$.

Comment: Oh..WOW-Well I feel stupid. Thank you so much, and sorry about the wrong edits.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
\begin{align}
S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k-1}
\end{align}
which can be seen as the following.
\begin{align}
S_{n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k-1} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} x^{k-1} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} x^{k-1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{k-1} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{n+k} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{n}}{1-x} = \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}.
\end{align}
Now, when $x=1/2$ this becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = 2-2^{1-n} = \frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n}}. 
\end{align}
when $n=7$ this is further reduced to
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{7} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = \frac{127}{64}.
\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by 40 yields the answer desired, namely,
\begin{align}
40 \sum_{k=1}^{7} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = \frac{635}{8}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{7}40 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = \frac{635}{8}$$

Take the left hand side and factor out constants:

$$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{7}40 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} = 20 \sum\limits_{k=1}^7 \left(\frac 12\right)^k$$

Then use $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n r^k = \frac{r(1-r^n)}{1-r}$, where $r=\frac 12, n=7$